# Is there a drawback to skipping the prologue?

Tags: star-wars-kotor-2

I just recently started playing Kotor2.

In the beginning, when you're in the medbay and the player controls the android, there was the chance to skip the prologue and I took it.

Since I'm not very advanced in the game, however, I was thinking about restarting to gain possible boons I might have missed, like items, XP or force points.

Was there anything of value I missed?

Also, if there are there any other skippable scenes in the game, the questions count for those as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything gained in the **Prologue** is lost. It is merely a **tutorial**.

I cannot consider later skippable scenes, because there is a lot of variation and complexity when it comes to benefits and drawbacks.

Note: There won't be any scenes past the **Prologue** that ask if you want to skip it. However, there could be scenes that you *miss* as you play the game, in which case, you may be missing out on loot, experience, or an ambush.

Edit: npst pointed out that there is a Steam achievement for completing the Prologue if you play KotOR2 on Steam.

Comment: There is a steam achievement for completing the prologue.

Comment: @npst Thanks for the heads up, I will edit my post. They must have added achievements fairly recently. I also didn't use Steam to play KotOR2 myself :/